# Parse javascript SDK ,Can not add user in role

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

My code for adding user in a Role named admin :

```
var Thisuser = Parse.User.current();
var rolequery= new Parse.Query(Parse.Role);

rolequery.equalTo("name","admin");

var Role = rolequery.find({
    success: function(Role) {
        alert("Successfully retrieved " + Role.length + " roles");

        // this line shows that there is one element named "admin" by resulting "Role.length"=1

        for (var i = 0; i < Role.length; i++) { 
            var object = Role[i];
            alert(object.id + ' - ' + object.get('name'));

            //outputs "admin",So till here code is right and working.
        }
    },
});

Role.getUsers().add(Thisuser);  //here is something wrong..
```

Comment: Please format your code in your questions for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
var Role = rolequery.find({
```

Is assigning the Parse.Promise to the `Role` variable in the outer scope.

Due to the nature of async code, the next line to be executed is the following line (not the inner success function):

```
Role.getUsers().add(Thisuser);
```

This of course fails because a Parse.Promise doesn't have a `getUsers()` method.

Later when the query finishes running, your inner success function is called and a scoped variable also called `Role` is assigned the array results. Inside the bounds of that function you're getting closer to what you expect.

**Note:**

It seems like there are some core concepts you need to get a greater understanding of, I would suggest learning more about "scope" and "asynchronous programming".

You'll also make life easier for yourself if you learn more about naming standards, when to use lowerCamelCase, UpperCamelCase and plural/singular names.